# Why is there underline on my links after css "reset"?

Tags: html, css

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zY3rL/1/

In my CSS I reset the link styling by doing the following:

```
@import "http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.0/normalize.css"
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300"

a { text-decoration: none; }
ol,ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Why then does the links in this code still have underline?

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="">Invoicing</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Create an Invoice</a></li>
            <li><a href="">View sent Invoices</a></li>
            <li><a href="">View rejected Invoices</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you include all the CSS / HTML needed to diagnose the problem in the question itself?

Comment: We've already figured it out, with a working fiddle below.

Comment: Why the dovnvote? It's an hones mistake and I didn't see the missing ';'
George: Short code is in my example and the rest in fiddle.

Comment: George, you might have a bad day, but don't be so hasty to downvote or report a question. I've also updated the Q with enough code to see the problem.

Comment: I agree, it might be a question about a silly thing that Steven oversaw, but that doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: @Steven The problem was that your 'short code' didn't reproduce the problem you have.  If questions are incomplete, they're put on hold. It's not a reflection on you, but it's one of the ways we ensure that people take the time to give us the information we need to solve their problems. It also ensures that if JSFiddle dies (which it has done on many occasions), future visitors don't become frustrated that a question doesn't have the information they need to help with their own issues.

Comment: @LinkinTED You ought to read the on hold reason (I agree that the words 'off topic' are a misnomer, but I didn't create the close bold text): "This question appears to be off-topic **because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or **include a minimal example in the question itself."** (emphasis mine). If we can't reproduce the issue from the text in the question itself, the question should be put on hold until that happens. This is site wide.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You only need **sufficient** information or **minimal example** of the code to see the problem. My Q has both. So if you want to blow of some steam, find a punching bag or a debate forum.

Comment: @Steven the [original revision of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/343a22df-3000-4ad9-8363-78a9c4ab97c7/view-source) did not have the part of the code that was the problem (the import statements).  Because of that there would be no way for someone to see your question and figure out what the problem was.  That's why it was put on hold. You then edited your question and included the *necessary* information and I re-opened it.  I'm not sure why you are arguing that it was sufficient when you had to edit it to make it sufficient.

Comment: Also: I'm not sure why you're attributing malice or anger to any of my actions.  What I'm doing now *is a normal part of moderating Stack Overflow* and is part of what I do *daily*.  It's also what other users that have the necessary reputation do on a daily basis. You're not being treated differently than any other user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `;` behind each `@import` line. Since there were none, the first line of CSS wasn't being applied.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zY3rL/2/)**

Original:

```
@import "http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.0/normalize.css"
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300"

a { text-decoration: none; }

CSS continues...
```

Fixed:

```
@import "http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.0/normalize.css";
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300";

a { text-decoration: none; }


CSS continues...
```

Note the `;` behind each `@import` line.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes one just goes blind on your own code!